# How to get value of logged in user id in controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Top of my controller i have added:

```
use Auth;
```

function in my controller

```
public function details($id)
{
   if(Auth::check())       
   { 
      $user = Auth::user();
      $product =  Product::find($id);    

      $cart->product_id = $product->id;
      $cart->category_id = $product->category_id;
      $cart->user_id = $user->id;

      dd($cart->user_id); //check if its storing the value
   }
   else {
     return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

when I run this i get error:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

If I remove the $user->id line the error goes.

I tried adding constructor also but still got same error

```
public function __construct() {

  $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

dd is showing other details after it checks if user is logged in.

**Is there a way to get user id of logged in user from users table that is created by default.**

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using middleware to protect routes rather than checking in your controller actions that a user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you’re calling `$cart->product_id`, but the `$cart` variable isn’t defined as far as I can see. PHP doesn’t know what to do, so because you try and assign a property to it, PHP assumes you want `$cart` to be a class, hence the “Creating default object from empty value” message.

Other than that, you code could be improved by using middleware to authenticate your users, and relations on your Eloquent models so you’re not manually assigning relation IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,
You forgot to initials cart object

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->product_id = $product->id;
$cart->category_id = $product->category_id;
$cart->user_id = $user->id;

dd($cart->user_id); //check if its storing the value
```